# font.letterspacing and text alignment

Tags: text, qml

I am trying to center text in a QML application using the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pointSize: 14
        font.letterSpacing: 20
    }
}
```

Without letter spacing, the text is centered, otherwise it's not.

Is it possible to visually center text with non-default letter spacing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full example. This is not valid QML, and the rest of the code affects both the context of the question and any potential answers.

Comment: @Mitch, should I put a minimal qtquick project here or qml file would be enough?

Comment: Just a single main.qml is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, width of the font.letterSpacing is a part of a letter.
To balance letterSpacing at the end I have added a space char at the beginning.

It is not perfectly centered but a way better than it was.

```
Text {
        text: " " + qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pointSize: 14
        font.letterSpacing: 20
    }
```